# Desktop VSCode vs Anaconda VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have vscode installed on my computer already. I noticed a while back that it is now included with the anaconda distribution. Is there any benefit to using the vscode included with anaconda vs the vscode i already have installed?

FYI im a python developer if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, VS Code is an independent (in terms of your question!) software which is just shipped with Anaconda. It does not matter if you install them separately or first install Anaconda and install VS Code from there. Anaconda add some extensions by default to VS Code, but you can always install them yourself.

What you can do is updating your VS Code when new versions are released (see https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Also, VS Code is a code editor and one might use it with Python installed from for instance python.org or Anaconda distribution. You can tell VS Code what is your Python path in the settings.

And finally you may want to read this (quoted form https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/vscode/):

> VS Code is free for both private and commercial use, runs on Windows, macOS and Linux, and includes support for linting, debugging, task running, version control and Git integration, IntelliSense code completion and conda environments.
>
> VS Code is openly extensible and many extensions are available. When you install VS Code with Anaconda it comes with the Python Extension for Visual Studio Code for editing Python code, and the RedHat YAML extension for editing YAML files such as conda configuration files.
>
> When installing Anaconda, you may select whether to install VS Code. VS Code is not offered during silent mode Anaconda installs, but you can easily install VS Code after the Anaconda install completes.

Comment: Just to add a little bit more detail, the only difference is the copy of VS Code that is downloaded from code.visualstudio.com versus coming with Anaconda is the latter comes with the [Anaconda extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.anaconda-extension-pack) out-of-the-box.