# Difference from launching vscode from anaconda navigator vs desktop shortcut

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

Short question, not necessarily related to the installation (like in [desktop-vscode-vs-anaconda-vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894897/desktop-vscode-vs-anaconda-vscode) ), but more with launching the application.

I installed vscode from the official page, the version without admin requirements because the version I installed from Anaconda couldn't update (don't know if that should happen. I don't have Admin privilegies in work so I blame that). The non-admin version recognizes my anaconda-python environments and seem to run fine except with the terminal, that doesn't recognize the "conda" command. The problem is solved by launching vscode (non-admin version again) from the Anaconda navigator or from anaconda prompt.

What is the difference from launching from the navigator vs launching from my desktop shortcut? The only difference I can recognize from launching the two ways is that the anaconda version allows for more than one shell on terminal, and displays "conda" as the shell.
Is there a way to create a shortcut from the anaconda prompt?

Comment: Just wanted to add that I added conda commands in vscode settings shell arguments. The terminal launches fine but a second slower it seems. Tried also using the conda path setting in the Python extension, any idea what it does? Could those settings be what anaconda changes on launch?

Answer (score 0):

The difference will be that Anaconda Navigator seems to be setting up your environment variables so that VS Code is launched it's from an activate conda environment (probably `base`). The VS Code shortcut doesn't have the equivalent setup.

There's no way to replicate the experience that I'm aware of, but maybe if you look at the Anaconda Prompt shortcut you can see what they are doing to duplicate it. Otherwise launching from the Anaconda Prompt or Navigator is going to be your best option.

Comment: I added the anaconda promt commands to the powershell shell arguments on vscode, so that every terminal executes conda correctly, although it seems to run a second slower than when launching from anaconda. I wonder if anaconda just adds those conda arguments to the shell