# Anaconda + VSCode vs Desktop VSCode alone

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894897/desktop-vscode-vs-anaconda-vscode) says that the only difference between those two is that the Anaconda version comes with the Anaconda extension pack out-of-the-box. However, I have been working with some project with both of them and I seen some starking differences and I'm wondering if somebody have some explanation for them (I work with Jupyter notebooks mostly as I'm a Data Scientist, if that information matters)

So, I have a folder that represents the whole project. Inside that folder I have multiple notebooks, datasets, visualizations, etc. I'm working with one of those notebooks specifically.

1. Yesterday I opened that notebook with VSCode from Anaconda (let's call it A-VSCode), and worked normally, at the end of the day I saved the changes. No problem. However, today I open the VSCode Desktop (let's call it D-VSCode) and it didn't have any of the work I did yesterday! And as it was the same notebook in the same folder, I was scared as hell as I thought I have lost a full day of work. However, when I open the same notebook with A-VSCode the whole work is there. **So I'm wondering if that's the same notebook, how A-VSCode (or D-VSCode?) keeps a different version? Where is that version saved?**
2. When I try to use the terminal, A-VSCode shows a different path than the D-VSCode. Why?, and why A-VSCode automatically activate the base environment if I have a specific environment for that notebook?

A-VSCode terminal:

```
PS E:\all_my_projects\project_A> E:/anaconda3/Scripts/activate
PS E:\all_my_projects\project_A> conda activate base
PS E:\all_my_projects\project_A>
```

D-VSCode terminal:

```
PS E:\all_my_projects\project_A>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue may be related to the operating mode of github uploads/downloads to/from the **repository**.

For the second question, I didn't see any differences in the path. The **automatic activation environment** is provided by the Python extension. You can refer to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

If you want to prevent automatic activation of a selected environment, you could add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false
```